# Need a Full Text Search sample

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, full-text-search

Can anyone please provide me a working sproc which contains something like this :

> WHERE CONTAINS(cars.brand ,
>   COALESCE(@brand,cars.brand)) AND

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, but your WHERE clause needs work.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[theSprocName]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[theSprocName]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.theSprocName

    @brand varchar(250)      -- change to suit the anticipated width.

AS

BEGIN

    SELECT SomeField1, SomeField2
    FROM cars
    -- specify what criteria to filter by.
    -- WHERE cars.brand 

END
GO
```